# Convert binary string greater than 52 bits to single in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm trying to convert very long binary strings, often greater than 52 bits into numbers. I cannot have a fixed lookahead window because I am doing this to calculate a version of Lempel-Ziv complexity for neural data.

When I try to convert any long string, bin2dec throws and error that the binary string must be 52 bits or less.

Is there a way to get around this size limitation?

Comment: How much precision do you need ? And what is the max no of bits ?

Comment: It's unknown. This is part of a research project. In any case, I estimate that I will need to convert binary strings of, at most, length 1e6. It would be great to get as close to that as possible. I maybe be missing something though, because I noticed that ceil(log2(1e6)) is only 20.

Comment: 1e6 bits represents a value of pow(2,1e6) which is a decimal value of around 10^300000. Are you *sure* you need to work with numbers this large (i.e. much greater than the number of fundamental particles in the universe) ?

Comment: The length of the string I'd pass to a function like dec2bin could be as long as 1e6. It comes from sampling a process 1e4 times per second and I expect patterns to last for around 100s. I'm using the decimal value of the binary string as a hash to build the lookup table for calculating LZ complexity.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `dec2bin` not `bin2dec`? `dec2bin` converts a number *into binary*, not a binary string into a number...

Comment: @aardvarkk: You're right. I'm using bin2dec. I corrected the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dec2bin` throws that error because a single is not capable of storing that much precision.  Your very question asks an impossibility.  You have two choices: store the value in something other than a floating point value, or throw away some precision before you convert.

Or describe more completely what you're trying to accomplish.

EDITING:

Based on your additional information, I am even more certain that converting to floating point is not what you want to do.  If you want to reduce the storage size to something more efficient, convert to a vector of bytes (uint8), which is as dense as you can get.  Just split the binary string into N rows of 8 digits each, using reshape.  This seems to be an accepted approach for biological data.

```
str = char((rand(1, 100)>0.5) + '0');    % test data
data = uint8(bin2dec(reshape(str(1:end-mod(end,8)), [], 8)));
```

In this code, I toss any bits that don't divide evenly into 8.  Or, skip the uint8 step and just perform your processing on the resulting vector, where each double-precision float represents one 8-bit word from your sequence.

Comment: I asked to help find a way around it.

Comment: Your additional comments helped clarify your goal.  See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could roll your own implementation:

```
len = 60;

string = [];
for i = 1:len
  string = [string sprintf('%d', randi([0 1]))];
end

% error
% bin2dec(string);

% roll your own...
value = 0;
for i = length(string):-1:1
  value = value + str2num(string(i))*2^(length(string)-i);
end
```

I'm just looping through the string and adding to some value. At the end, value will contain the decimal value of the string. Does this work for you?

**Note:** This solution is *slow*. You can speed it up a bit by preallocating the string, which I did on my own machine. Also, it's going to have issues if your number gets up to 1e6 digits. At that point, you need variable precision arithmetic to keep track of it. And adding that to the calculation *really* slowed things down. If I were you, I'd strongly consider compiling this from a `.mex` file if you need the functionality in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

credits due to @aardvarkk, but here's a sped up version of his algorithm (+- 100x faster):

```
N=100;
strbin = char(randi(2,1,N)+'0'-1);

pows2 = 2.^(N-1:-1:0);
value=pows2*(strbin-'0')';
```

`double`'s range goes only up to `1.79769e+308` which is `2^1024` give or take. From there on, `value` will be `Inf` or `NaN`. So you still need to find another way storing the resulting number.

A final pro on this algorithm: you can cache `pows2` for a large number and then use a piece of it for any new strbin of length N:

```
Nmax = 1e8; % already 700MB for pows2, watch out!
pows2 = 2.^(Nmax-1:-1:0);
```

and then use

```
value = pows2(Nmax-N+1:end)*(strbin-'0')';
```

### Solution to matlab's numeric upper bound

There's a tool on the File Exchange called vpi: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725

It allows you to use really big integers (`2^5000`? no prob). It's only slower (a lot) in calculating everything, I don't suggest using my method above with this. But hey, you can't have everything!

Download the package, `addpath` it and the following might work:

```
N=3000;
strbin = char(randi(2,1,N)+'0'-1);

binvals=strbin-'0';
val=0;
twopow=vpi(1);
for ii=1:N
    val=val+twopow*binvals(N-ii+1);
    twopow=twopow*2;
end
```

Comment: Note that double only has 52 bits of precision (which is probably where the 52 bit limit comes from in bin2dec).